# vim mapping keys to surround words/lines with <p></p>

Tags: vim, surround

I'm trying to map the keys ALT+SHIFT+W to surround the text/line with `<p></p>` tags.

Right now I have this on my _vimrc file:

```
map <A-S-w> c<p><C-R>"<p><ESC>
```

But this produces:

```
<p>Some text.<p></p></p>
```

What I'm doing wrong? I have to scape the first "`<p>`" on my map?

Thanks

Comment: You should check out the surround plugin: http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697

Comment: I agree with @Matteo : although the answers are valid, what you want here is the surround plug-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote wrong mapping. The correct is:

```
map <A-S-w> c<p><C-R>"</p><ESC>
```

Comment: thanks! I feel dumb.. but I have a plugin that auto-closes that p, so this is the main problem there.. now I got this working.

Comment: @Homem Robo, @black You all should use `nore` (`noremap`). If you did, this problem would not appear because that plugin mapping have not been invoked. It is a general rule while writing *any* mapping: use `nore` unless {rhs} contains only *known* *remapped* key sequences (like `<Plug>Something`). *Known* and *remapped* or you may run into trouble.

Comment: Done! `noremap <A-S-w> c<p><C-R>"</p><ESC>`

Answer (score 2):

This has already been answered, but may I suggest a version that doesn't overwrite the default register:

```
vnoremap <A-S-w> <ESC>`>a<\p><ESC>`<i<p><ESC>
```

It makes use of the < and > markers to go to the most recent visual selection. Note that `vnoremap` is safer than a basic `map` because (a) it is restricted to visual mode, and (b) it is non-recursive.

Comment: I'm new on vim, so I still don't get the visual mode on my workflow right now. I have to learn more of vim. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: A visual selection is anything selected by pressing `v`, `V` or `<c-v>`, so I assumed that's what you were doing. It's a good habit to use `noremap` unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: Actually I'm having trouble with vim modes right now. I have this on my vimrc: behave mswin. This is not good right?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `behave mswin` (although I don't use it). One of its side-effects to remap `<c-v>` to paste, so block-wise visual mode is remapped to `<c-q>`.